# Need suggestions on optimizing this code

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

Currently when I read a 15Mb file my application goes over a gig of memory.
Notice that, at the end of the main code, I compare the data that was inserted in the database with the original array from the file. Any suggestions are welcome.

Main code:

```
TestEntities entities = new TestEntities();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName + ".exe", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];

            int numBytesToRead = (int) fileStream.Length;
            int numBytesRead = 0;

            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int n = fileStream.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                if (n == 0)
                    break;

                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }

            var query = bytes.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i, Value = x})
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index/100)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToList();

            foreach (List<byte> list in query)
            {
                Binary binary = new Binary();
                binary.Name = fileName + ".exe";
                binary.Value = list.ToArray();
                entities.AddToBinaries(binary);
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();

            List<Binary> fileString = entities.Binaries.Where(b => b.Name == fileName + ".exe").ToList();

            Byte[] final = ExtractArray(fileString);
            if (Compare(bytes, final))
            {
                 /// Some notification that was ok
            }

        }
```

Compare Method:

```
public bool Compare(Byte[] array1,Byte[] array2)
    {
        bool isEqual = false;
        if (array1.Count() == array2.Count())
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Count(); i++)
            {
                isEqual = array1[i] == array2[i];
                if (!isEqual)
                {
                    break;

                }
            }
        }


        return isEqual;
    }
```

ExtractArray Method:

```
public Byte[] ExtractArray(List<Binary> binaries )
    {
        List<Byte> finalArray = new List<Byte>();

        foreach (Binary binary in binaries)
        {
            foreach (byte b in binary.Value)
            {
                finalArray.Add(b);
            }

        }

        return finalArray.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Comparing large binary objects can be done using the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968935/c-sharp-binary-file-compare

Comment: Is all you are doing a byte for byte comparison of two files? why do you do all this?

Comment: why don't you store a digest of the files in the database and just digest the other ones, rather than comparing every time?

Comment: I am segmenting the file and storing in the database, since the segmentation could be wrong, and I can't have that, I read it back from the database, and verify if it was written correctly.

Comment: if you have working code that you want peer reviewed for improvement/optimization, your question belongs on [codereview.se] instead, which was created specifically for that purpose. This site is for issues with code that isn't working.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the comment, as you may not have seen this post was done in 2012. I am not sure if the "Code Review" area was popular at the time or if it even existed, but thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I'd strongly recommend that you invest in a profiler.  That's the right way to determine why your code is taking so long to run or is using a lot of memory.  There are many profilers out there, including [one built into Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) if you have Premium or Ultimate.

See google or these post for others:

[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

and

[Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-net-memory-and-performance-profiler)

Secondly, you probably shouldn't be assuming that your app *should'nt* go over a gig of memory.  C# applications (actually, all .NET applications) are garbage collected.  If I have a computer with sufficient RAM, there is no reason why the GC should run if there is no memory pressure, and if it doesn't the application can easily use up a gig of memory.  That is particularly true for 64-bit environments, where processes are not subject to the memory limits of a 32-bit address space.

Comment: I do need to get a profiler, but in this case the profile will tell what I already know, since there isn't much code here, so crowdsorcing for better ideas is the best option.

Comment: On your second point when the application reads a 15Mb file and it goes up to 6Gb in memory, something is really wrong, and thats what happening now.

Answer (score 0):

At first two variant of comapre:

```
bool arraysAreEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);
```

or this one

```
    public bool Compare(Byte[] array1, Byte[] array2)
    {
        if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i] != array2[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;            
    }
```

About extract try this:

```
foreach (Binary binary in binaries)
{
     finalArray.AddRange(binary.Value);
}
```

Comment: Prefer Array.Length to IEnumerable.Count().

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you know the static method [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) ? Could save you the first fifteen lines of code.

2) I hate Linq... Unreadable and it's so hard to understand what is really going on.

```
        var query = bytes.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i, Value = x})
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index/100)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

So for each byte of your file, you create an object containing the byte itself and its index. Wow. If your file is 15mb, that's 15 728 640 objects. Lets say this object takes 64 bytes, that's 960mb of memory space.

Btw, what are you trying to do ?

**Edit**

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

var chunkCount = (int)Math.Ceilling(bytes.Length / 100.0);

var chunks = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>(chunkCount);


for(int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
  chunks.Add(new ArraySegment(
      bytes,
      i * 100,
      Math.Min(100, bytes.Length - i * 100)
  ));
}
```

This should be several times faster.

Still, for better performances, you might insert chunks in database as you read the file, without keeping all those bytes in memory.

Comment: So the GroupBy part, tries to divide the file in a bunch of 100 bytes long chucks and then each chunk is inserted in the database. Later I can pull all the chunks and rebuild the file.